# The SELECT permission was denied on the object '__EFMigrationsHistory', database 'master', schema 'dbo'

Tags: permissions, query, schema-migration

I'm trying to create asp.net core web api. (https://youtu.be/EmV_IBYIlyo?si=GcPVN7BuautDy6-j&t=1351)  At the point where he executes Add-Migration InitialCreate and Update-database my console spits out error:

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object
> '__EFMigrationsHistory', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.

Database is an AzureSQL. It's fresh and new. I use administrator (aka owner) credentials. My question is:

How correctly configure user that could execute and have permission to SELECT and INSERT data into __EFMigrationsHistory table.

I also tried to follow this document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage?view=azuresql), however if I try to do any actions with ALTER SERVER ROLE it says that I don't have permissions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use "Catalog" in connection string. First notice, that it should not require access to master database.